# Schedule a shell script every day at 13 CET without crontab

Tags: aix, scheduling

I am developing a ksh shell script in AIX server which have to be exactly run at 13:00 on every day. I don't have permission to use CRONTAB, AT, WATCH, inotify, date -d, etc.
The only option is use to make the script to loop continuously and run in the background.

```
while [ $(date +%H%M) != 1300 ]
do
actions
sleep 60
done
```

I tried the above code but I don't want the `while` to run continuously in the background until the condition becomes true. Suggest me any other way to use `sleep` or `while` loop or any which runs only one time instead of continuously.

Comment: Can you schedule it externally from the AIX system, and have that system connect in to run the script?

Comment: Can anyone tell me why my question was marked as -1?

Comment: Votes are anonymous but as an AIX systems administrator,  my first thought was that your question fails the "useful" test. It's at best an artificial challenge to find creative ways to schedule a job, and at worst looking to work around restrictions put in place by the administrator. The typical ways to schedule a job *are* cron and at. You then say the only option is a continuous while/sleep script which you then say you don't want. What kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: I mentioned clearly in the question "Suggest me any other way to use sleep or while loop or any which runs only one time instead of continuously."

Comment: Your best bet seems to me to be to find a way to do date math in AIX, and compute the number of seconds between now and 13:00, sleep X && run job, then enter a sleep 24hr loop. Also disassociate it from your login session, probably.

Answer (score 0):

I've only done it in `perl`, and never used `ksh`, but I don't see why it shouldn't be possible, but I've done it somewhat like (probably not valid code in any language):

```
while(true)
    starttime=`date +%s`
    actions
    sleep starttime+24*60*60-`date +%s`
end
```

That only makes the actions start every 24'th hour. My thought was for getting it to run at 13:00 was just add a loop at the start that waits until 13:00. Thinking about it it might be better to replace `starttime+24*60*60` with something like `date -d "13:00 tomorrow" +%s`.

Comment: This won't survive a reboot, will miss the expected hour after a timezone change (a regression compared to the OP script), and need extra work to stay running if the remote connection is closed. Note that the OP stated `date -d` was not available.